# How to get the deployment version in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, deployment

I want to save deployment version in DB from where I can get the currently deployed version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to get the current deployed version. Thanks @Black

```php
<?php

namespace MyModule\MyVendor\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\View\Deployment\Version\StorageInterface;

class DeploymentVersion
{
    /**
     * @var StorageInterface
     */
    protected $storage;

    /**
     * @var int|boolean|null
     */
    protected $deployedVersion;

    /**
     * constructor
     * @param StorageInterface $storage
     */
    public function __construct(
        StorageInterface $storage
    ) {
        $this->storage = $storage;
    }

    public function getDeploymentId()
    {
        if (!isset($this->deployedVersion)) {
            $this->deployedVersion = $this->storage->load();
        }

        return $this->deployedVersion;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is stored in `pub/static/deployed_version.txt`

Comment: Thanks, but Is Magento have anything to get current version ?

Comment: Do you mean a function?

Comment: Thanks @Black I have added an answer!